# How to use my Arrays and reference elements within one to compare values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, dynamics-crm

Context- CRM system, front-end form.

Requirement- Within a form users have to give a rating to a section based on user inputs, each rating has different weighting. The rating is stored in an option set field and the weighting for that rating is stored in another option set field. I have used JavaScript to calculate the average score of these rating fields through lots of variables.

I am now trying to use objects and methods to do this, although I do not quite understand how I achieve this.

Below is my code block, as you can see I get two fields from the form. Now I would like to use an array to compare the value in my Score Option A field with my Score Array and set the score from this.

For example ScoreOptionA = 778180000, so check that it matches a value in my array and based on the match set the score for ScoreOptionAValue to 1.

```
function CalculateAverageScore(executionContext) {
    alert("triggerd");
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var ScoreOptionA = formContext.getAttribute("dp_sectionamanagerrating").getValue();
    var PercentageOptionA = formContext.getAttribute("dp_sectionaquestionweighting").getValue();
    alert(ScoreOptionA);
    // Define the score array
    var score = [
        { "value": 778180000, "score": 1 },
        { "value": 778180001, "score": 2 },
        { "value": 778180002, "score": 3 },
        { "value": 778180003, "score": 4 },
        { "value": 778180004, "score": 5 }
    ];
    // Define the percentage array
    var percentage = [
        { "value": 778180000, "score": 0.10 },
        { "value": 778180001, "score": 0.20 },
        { "value": 778180002, "score": 0.30 },
        { "value": 778180003, "score": 0.40 },
        { "value": 778180004, "score": 0.50 }
    ];
    var SectionAScore = score.find(function (item) {
        return item.value === ScoreOptionA;
    });
    if (SectionAScore) {
        var ScoreOptionAValue = SectionAScore.score;
        alert("score found: " + ScoreOptionAValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is.  Are you just asking how to *write a loop* in JavaScript?  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: `check that it matches a value in my array` what if it matches all the values in your array?

Comment: Are the values in your array supposed to be the same? If so, why not just hard code the value to a constant?

Comment: You can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate an element with a particular property value.  [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xhao9js7)

Comment: My mistake the values are not supposed to be the same, I have uploaded the correct code now and showed how I am trying to use the Array and the find function.